# Setting priority of interrupt in NVIC_PR register

Tags: arm, interrupt, cortex-m

I believe I've understood the concept of interrupt and how to initialize it, but I've seen in various places where they would first AND (select) the NVIC_PR registers against F bits before (ORing) the priority bits. For example in [TM4C123 GPIO Port Interrupt Programming](http://shukra.cedt.iisc.ernet.in/edwiki/EmSys:TM4C123_GPIO_Port_Interrupt_Programming) there was this line towards the end:

```
NVIC_PRI7_R = (NVIC_PRI7_R & 0xFF00FFFF) | 0x00A00000
```

The purpose is to set Port F interrupt a priority of 5 (by setting the top 3 bits `[23:21]` to the value; hence .1010. or 0xA to represent the a value of 5). So, why can't I just do this instead?

```
NVIC_PRI7_R |= 0x00A00000
```

What is `& 0xFF00FFFF` doing here? Why do I want to clear bits [23:16] before OR-ing priority bits `[23:21]`? The bits between `[20:16]` are not used anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If bits `[23:21]` were all already set to 1, then `NVIC_PRI7_R |= 0x00A00000` does nothing, it doesn't set them to the value you want, they all stay as 1s, that's why you clear them before applying your mask. The `&` with `0xFF00FFFF` ensures that only the bits `[23:16]` are modified, the rest are left as they were.

Comment: If `[23:21]` were already set to 1, regardless of whether `NVIC_PRI7_R |= 0x00A00000` causes any actual change of bits wouldn't matter to the end result - that is `[23:21]` will be 1's and that's all that matter (unless there are some sort of edge-triggering here?). Second is if we were to explicitly clear `NVIC_PRI7_R` register, shouldn't I be doing this: `NVIC_PRI7_R & 0x00000000`? Alternatively if I were to keep other bits unaffected and clear just `[23:21]`, shouldn't that be `NVIC_PRI7_R & 0xFF0FFFFF` to clear `[23:21]` specifically instead of the double zero `00` clearing out `[23:16]`?

Comment: If you're wanting to set the priority to 5 by setting those bits to 101, but they're already 111 then you end up with priority 7, that may or may not be a problem in your application. You're right, if you're only interested in those 3 bits you could `& 0xFF1FFFFF`, without studying the datasheet more I don't know why the linked article suggests `&0xFF00FFFF`